# packageが適用される範囲は1ファイルですか？

Tags: go

**packageが適用される範囲は1ファイルですか？**
・1つのファイルで複数のパッケージを定義することは出来ない？？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

はい、1つのファイルは1つのパッケージにのみ対応します。

仕様の https://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages にも以下のように書かれています。

> #### Source file organization
>
> Each source file consists of a package clause defining the package to which it belongs, followed by a possibly empty set of import declarations that declare packages whose contents it wishes to use, followed by a possibly empty set of declarations of functions, types, variables, and constants.
>
> ```
> SourceFile       = PackageClause ";" { ImportDecl ";" } { TopLevelDecl ";" } .
> ```